# Custom loss with loops in tensorflow

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, tensor, loss-function

I have a function in my data prepocessing which performs a blockwise DCT on 3D numpy arrays in YCbCr-mode.

```
def perform_blockwise_dct(img, ratio):

    imsize = img.shape
    dct_blocks = np.zeros(imsize)

    for i in np.r_[:imsize[0]:8]:
        for j in np.r_[:imsize[1]:8]:

            dct_blocks[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 0] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 0].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
            dct_blocks[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 1] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 1].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
            dct_blocks[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 2] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8),j:(j+8), 2].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')

    return dct_blocks
```

To be able to implement a custom mean square error function I would like to reverse this function. The problem is that when implementing the loss function it is a tensorflow tensor. There is an inverse DCT function to use. However, I do not know how to perform an equivilent double for-loop to do it block-wise. Currently it is done on the entire image, like this:

```
    def mse_custom_loss(a, b)
        y = tf.spectral.idct(a[:,:,0], norm='ortho') 
        cb = tf.spectral.idct(a[:,:,1], norm='ortho')
        cr = tf.spectral.idct(a[:,:,2], norm='ortho') 
        a = K.stack([y, cb, cr], axis=-1)

        y = tf.spectral.idct(b[:,:,0], norm='ortho') 
        cb = tf.spectral.idct(b[:,:,1], norm='ortho')
        cr = tf.spectral.idct(b[:,:,2], norm='ortho') 
        b = K.stack([y, cb, cr], axis=-1)

        return mean_square_error(a, b)
```

Any ideas on how to do it correctly? I assume lambda functions might be a possibility?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with DCT or signal processing in general, but it seems in `perform_blockwise_dct` you are using `dct` twice to make a 2D DCT and in `mse_custom_loss` you are using `idct` once, which would give you a 1D IDCT over the last dimension. Which one is right? Also, for the loss function, will `a` and `b` be individual images (3D tensors) or batches of images (4D tensors)?

Comment: True, it should be 2D DCT for each channel. For instance an image of shape (128, 128, 3). In other words, in the custom loss function it should only be 2D and not 1D. Regarding a and b, these are individual images (3D tensors) and not batches of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a TensorFlow equivalent to your NumPy/SciPy function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def perform_blockwise_dct_tf(img):
    shape = tf.shape(img)
    x, y, c = shape[0], shape[1], shape[2]
    img_res = tf.reshape(img, [x // 8, 8, y // 8, 8, c])
    img_dct1 = tf.spectral.dct(tf.transpose(img_res, [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]), norm='ortho')
    img_dct2 = tf.spectral.dct(tf.transpose(img_dct1, [0, 2, 4, 3, 1]), norm='ortho')
    out = tf.reshape(tf.transpose(img_dct2, [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]), shape)
    return out
```

A small test:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import dct

def perform_blockwise_dct(img):
    imsize = img.shape
    dct_blocks = np.zeros(imsize, dtype=img.dtype)
    for i in np.r_[:imsize[0]:8]:
        for j in np.r_[:imsize[1]:8]:
            dct_blocks[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 0] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 0].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
            dct_blocks[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 1] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 1].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
            dct_blocks[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 2] = dct(dct(img[i:(i+8), j:(j+8), 2].T, norm='ortho').T, norm='ortho')
    return dct_blocks

np.random.seed(100)
# DCT in TensorFlow only supports float32
img = np.random.rand(128, 256, 3).astype(np.float32)
out1 = perform_blockwise_dct(img)
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    out2 = sess.run(perform_blockwise_dct_tf(img))
# There is a bit of error
print(np.allclose(out1, out2, rtol=1e-5, atol=1e-6))
# True
```